# Access SQL nested query as a dictionary for final query result in very long run. Ways to optimize?

Tags: sql, dictionary, ms-access-2010, subquery

Want to warn you that it relates to MS Access SQL, so full outer join and some other nice stuff doesn't work here. The code below (by my idea) creates dictionary of tuples from an initial query, then refines it into the next dictionary by selecting those LKAK that have multiple values of ChainCl(It could have only 2 possible values, but for each LKAK must be one value of ChainCl, so I do query that finds mistakes for me). My goal is, relying on that final dictionary-list of LKAK, to get records with those LKAK from the MS_FLT query (all of them are there, dictionary made of its values) and RC_FLT query (values from dictionary are present there partially, but still are). Creation of final dictionary works just fine and instant. However, when I come to withdrawing the records, query run for about 20 min through 130000 records. What could be done to optimize the speed in connection between dictionary and source query. Note that adding "distinct" after the first "select" doesn't change run speed significantly. My problem is that I need to get joined results (using union) from three same-way formatted tables-queries(say, RC,RW,RE), and if one takes 20 min, then three is an hour. This thing is quite useful for me and possibly others as a workaround for cases when you need to display extra data that doesn't take part in criteria involving totals needed "group by"(like count). Creation of additional query won't work for me either as I need to collect them within the single complex query(don't like the idea, but that's the requirement). So, any suggestions on optimization?

```
{select distinct
    RC_FLT.LKAK as DataKeyAccount,
    MS_FLT.LKAK as MasterKeyAccount,
    RC_FLT.LSTCK as DataSubTradeChannel,
    MS_FLT.LSTCK as MasterSubTradeChannel,
    RC_FLT.UFPCh as DataUFPChannel,
    MS_FLT.UFPCh as MasterUFPChannel,
    RC_FLT.ChainCl as DataChainClass,
    MS_FLT.ChainCl as MasterChainClass,
    RC_FLT.Mkt as MarketUnit
from 
    RC_FLT,
    MS_FLT
where
    RC_FLT.LSTCK=MS_FLT.LSTCK
    and RC_FLT.LKAK=MS_FLT.LKAK 
    and RC_FLT.ChainCl=MS_FLT.ChainCl 
    and MS_FLT.LKAK in(
        SELECT LKAK
        FROM (
            select distinct LKAK, ChainCl
            from MS_FLT)
        group by LKAK
        having count(LKAK)>1);}
```

PS In both initial queries, fields used are there, but there are other fields as well.

Comment: MS Access supports outer joins, just not `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: thank you for correction